# Unable to update the correct row of csv in GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Here I'm trying to to get a dropdown menu and using that I'm getting the labels in the required row of newly added column. But I'm unable to to update the desired row, some how only the row 11 is getting updated and not the one which I'm trying to.
This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

DEBUG = True
csv_data = pd.DataFrame()
csv_text = None
entry_values = {}
entry_widgets = []

def update_dropdown(row_index, value):
    # Update the DataFrame with the selected value
    csv_data.at[row_index, 'label'] = value

def open_image():
    image_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select Image')
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((400, 400))  # Adjust the size as per your preference
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_label.configure(image=photo)
    image_label.image = photo

def open_csv():
    global csv_data
    if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] open_csv()')

    csv_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select CSV File', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])

    if csv_path:
        csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        update_csv_display()
        create_entry_widgets()

        # remove old items in Treeview
        for item in my_tree.get_children():
            my_tree.delete(item)

        # add new items in Treeview
        for index in range(len(csv_data)):
            my_tree.insert("", "end", text=index)

def save_csv():
    global csv_data
    if DEBUG:
        print('[DEBUG] save_csv()')

    if csv_data is not None:
        csv_path = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save CSV File', defaultextension='.csv', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv')])
    csv_data.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
    print("CSV file saved successfully.")

def display_csv():
   if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] display_csv()')

   if csv_data is not None:
       for col in range(len(csv_data.columns)):
           label = tk.Label(csv_frame, text=csv_data.columns[col])
           label.pack()

           for row in range(len(csv_data)):
               entry = tk.Entry(csv_frame)
               entry.pack()
               entry.insert(tk.END, str(csv_data.iloc[row, col]))

def add_column():
   global csv_data
   if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] add_column()')
   if csv_data is not None:
       column_name = entry_column.get()
       column_name = column_name.strip()  # remove spaces at the ends.
       if column_name:  # check if name is not empty
           csv_data[column_name] = ''
           update_csv_display()
           create_entry_widgets()

def update_csv_display():
   if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] update_csv_display()')

   csv_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
   csv_text.insert(tk.END, csv_data.to_string())

def create_entry_widgets():
   global entry_values
   global entry_widgets

   if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] create_entry_widgets()')
   # remove all widgets from Frame
   for item in rows_frame.winfo_children():
       item.destroy()

   # create again all Entry widgets and all Treeview rows
   for index, col in enumerate(csv_data.columns):
       print('col:', col)
       entry_values[col] = tk.StringVar()

       entry = tk.Label(rows_frame, text=f"{col}:")
       entry.grid(row=index, column=0, sticky='e')

       entry = tk.Entry(rows_frame, textvariable=entry_values[col])
       entry.grid(row=index, column=1)

       if col == 'label':
          # Create a dropdown menu for the 'label' column
          dropdown = ttk.Combobox(rows_frame, values=[
            "invoice_number",
            "date",
            "time",
            "total",
            "vendor.name",
            "vendor.phone_number",
            "vendor.gst_number",
            "vendor.email",
            "vendor.website",
            "vendor.address",
            "customer.customer_name",
            "customer.phone_number"
        ], textvariable=entry_values[col])
          dropdown.grid(row=index, column=2)
          dropdown.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event, row_index=index: update_dropdown(row_index, entry_values[col].get()))

def get_selected_row_from_csv(event=None):
   global csv_data

   if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] get_selected_row_from_csv()')
   selected_items = my_tree.selection()
   print('selected_items:', selected_items)

   if selected_items:
       selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
       print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)

       selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
       print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)

       for col, value in entry_values.items():
           print(f"{col}: {value.get()}")
           entry_values[col].set(csv_data.at[selected_row, col])

def update_selected_row_in_csv():
   global csv_data

   if DEBUG:
       print('[DEBUG] update_selected_row_in_csv()')
   selected_items = my_tree.selection()

   if selected_items:
       selected_row_id = selected_items[0]
       print('Treeview row id:', selected_row_id)

    selected_row = my_tree.item(selected_row_id)['text']
    print('DataFrame row number:', selected_row)

    for col in csv_data.columns:
        csv_data.at[selected_row, col] = entry_values[col].get()

    update_csv_display()

# --- main ---

if DEBUG:
   print('[DEBUG] create_gui()')

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a frame for the image
image_frame = tk.Frame(root)
image_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create a label for displaying the image
image_label = tk.Label(image_frame)
image_label.pack()

# Create a button to open the image
image_button = tk.Button(image_frame, text='Open Image', command=open_image)
image_button.pack(pady=10)

# Create a frame for the CSV data
csv_frame = tk.Frame(root)
csv_frame.pack(side="left", padx=10, pady=10)

csv_text = tk.Text(csv_frame, width=160, height=15)
csv_text.pack()

# Create a button to open the CSV file
csv_button = tk.Button(csv_frame, text='Open CSV', command=open_csv)
csv_button.pack(pady=10)

# Create a button to save the CSV file
save_csv_button = tk.Button(csv_frame, text='Save CSV', command=save_csv)
save_csv_button.pack(pady=10)

# Add a column entry field and button for manual column addition
add_column_frame = tk.Frame(csv_frame)
add_column_frame.pack(pady=10)

entry_column = tk.Entry(add_column_frame, width=10)
entry_column.pack(padx=5, side="left")

add_column_button = tk.Button(add_column_frame, text='Add Column', command=add_column)
add_column_button.pack(side="left")

rows_frame = tk.Frame(csv_frame)
rows_frame.pack()

# Create a Treeview for displaying CSV data
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
my_tree.heading('#0', text='Select Row')

my_tree.pack(pady=20)

my_tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", get_selected_row_from_csv)
create_entry_widgets()

root.mainloop()
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @furas, can you please help me with this one, I'm really stuck and need some help in solving the issue. Thank you.